# Probability density of a random variable

Tags: probability

How to calculate the probability density of a random variable being the sum of independent random variables $X _{1}$ and $X _{2}$ with normal distributions $N( m _{1},  \partial ^{2}  _{1} )$ and $N( m _{2},  \partial ^{2}  _{2} )$? 
Any help?

Comment: This is one of those questions that is so readily answered in textbooks—even a google search of the phrase “sums of normal random variables” leads one directly to the wikipedia page titled so which explicitly answers the question—that it is extremely apparent you have not put sufficient thought or effort into the question yourself. This is not a free homework website and is not advertised as such...

Answer (score 2):

The sum of two normal random variables is normal (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) from there you can calculate the mean and variance of the distributions: $\mu = m_1 + m_2$ and same for the variance.

Comment: “and same for the variance”—the variance of a sum of normal RVs is only the sum of variances in the case of independence.